# ASP.NET WebForm - get table cell by string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking to get a TableCell by ID (of type string). The process is similar to getElementById in JavaScript. How will I do that in C#?

For example,

```
var tb = document.someFunction("jks_build_1"); // this should get JKS-BUILD1
```

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server">
    <asp:TableCell ID="jks_build_1" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black">JKS-BUILD1</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell ID="jks_build_2" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black">JKS-BUILD2</asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell ID="jks_build_dev" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black">JKS-BUILD-DEV</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

Comment: TableRow has a `.Cells[]` property, have you tried that?

Comment: Is it possible to pass a string into .Cells[] and get the appropriate TableCell?

For example, TableRow.Cells["jks_build_1"]; will get me JKS-BUILD1?

Comment: No (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecellcollection?view=netframework-4.8), but you could probably use Linq `Cells.FirstOrDefault(cell => cell.ID == "jks_build_1")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, why you don't just call the property .Text I mean

```
var t = jks_build_1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a better way to go about this, however my first instinct is to
Loop through the table row by row, cell by cell at the start of the program and build a dictionary using the ID string of the cells.

When you need to access a cell by ID, just reference that dictionary and you'll have what you need.

I also believe there is a .FindControlById() function or similar that you can call on the table, but that may or may not work.